# instantiate get form data in a class php

Tags: php, forms, class

I have a simple php form submitting a query into a few classes. The idea of app is to pass in a band name and check a venue to see if that band is playing. If that band is playing it the app will echo out the band and the date that band is playing. I have managed to get the app to work when its all one php file but i am having trouble spitting the single php file into separate classes.

html form :

```html
<form action = "Ass1.php" method = "GET">
 <b>Enter band name : </b>
 <input type="text" name="bandName" />
 <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Click" />
</form>
```

The entire php file that works:

```
<?php

        class Concert {

            public $Artist = '';
            public $Date = '';

            function SetConcert( $NewArtist = '', $NewDate = '' ) {

                $this->Artist = $NewArtist;
                $this->Date = $NewDate;

            }

            function GetArtist() {

                return $this->Artist;

            }

            function GetDate() {

                return $this->Date;

            }

        }

    class Venue {

                public $VenueName = '';
                public $ConcertsInVenue = array();

        function SetVenueName( $NewVenue = '' ) {

                    $this->VenueName = $NewVenue;

        }

                function GetVenueName() {

                    return $this->VenueName;

                }

                function AddConcert( $NewArtist = '', $NewDate = '' ) {

                    $NewConcert = new Concert;
                    $NewConcert->SetConcert( $NewArtist, $NewDate );

                    $this->ConcertsInVenue[] = $NewConcert;


                }

                function ListConcertsInVenue( $SearchQuery = '' ) {

                    //Assume Results Will Be Filtered
                    $ListAllConcerts = FALSE;

                    //If Search Query Is Blank, List All Concerts
                    if( $SearchQuery == '' ){

                        $ListAllConcerts = TRUE;

                    }

                    echo 'Concerts In '.$this->VenueName.':';

                    //Loop Through All Concerts In This Venue
                    foreach( $this->ConcertsInVenue as $tmpConcert ){

                        if( $SearchQuery == $tmpConcert->GetArtist() || $ListAllConcerts == TRUE ){

                            echo '<p>';
                            echo $tmpConcert->GetArtist().', ';
                            echo $tmpConcert->GetDate();
                            echo '</p>';

                        }

                    }

                }

        }

        //Create New Venue Object
    $tmpVenue = new Venue;

        //Set Venue Name
        $tmpVenue->SetVenueName( 'Wembley' );

        //Add Concerts To Venue
        $tmpVenue->AddConcert( 'Rollin\' Empire', '05-02-2018' );
        $tmpVenue->AddConcert( 'Metallica', '06-02-2018' );
        $tmpVenue->AddConcert( 'Led Zeppelin', '07-02-2018' );
        $tmpVenue->AddConcert( 'Rollin\' Empire', '19-02-2018' );

        //Search For Artist In Venue ( Leave Blank To List All )
        $tmpVenue->ListConcertsInVenue($_GET['bandName']);

?>
```

Ive tries creating 3 classes Venue.class.php Concert.class.php and app.class.php and its not working

concert.class.php

```html
<?php

include ("Venue.class.php");

class Concert {

    public $Artist = '';
    public $Date = '';

    function SetConcert( $NewArtist = '', $NewDate = '' ) {

     $this->Artist = $NewArtist;
     $this->Date = $NewDate;

    }

    function GetArtist() {

     return $this->Artist;

    }

    function GetDate() {

     return $this->Date;

    }

   }
?>
```

Venue.class.php

```html
<?php

include ("Concert.class.php");

 class Venue {

     public $VenueName = '';
     public $ConcertsInVenue = array();

         function SetVenueName( $NewVenue = '' ) {

      $this->VenueName = $NewVenue;

         }

     function GetVenueName() {

      return $this->VenueName;

     }

     function AddConcert( $NewArtist = '', $NewDate = '' ) {

      $NewConcert = new Concert;
      $NewConcert->SetConcert( $NewArtist, $NewDate );

      $this->ConcertsInVenue[] = $NewConcert;


     }

     function ListConcertsInVenue( $SearchQuery = '' ) {

      //Assume Results Will Be Filtered
      $ListAllConcerts = FALSE;

      //If Search Query Is Blank, List All Concerts
      if( $SearchQuery == '' ){

       $ListAllConcerts = TRUE;

      }

      echo 'Concerts In '.$this->VenueName.':';

      //Loop Through All Concerts In This Venue
      foreach( $this->ConcertsInVenue as $tmpConcert ){

       if( $SearchQuery == $tmpConcert->GetArtist() || $ListAllConcerts == TRUE ){

        echo '<p>';
        echo $tmpConcert->GetArtist().', ';
        echo $tmpConcert->GetDate();
        echo '</p>';

       }

      }

     }

      }

?>
```

app.php

```html
<?php

include ("Venue.class.php");
include ("Concert.class.php");

   //Create New Venue Object
     $tmpVenue = new Venue;

   //Set Venue Name
   $tmpVenue->SetVenueName( 'Wembley' );

   //Add Concerts To Venue
   $tmpVenue->AddConcert( 'Rollin\' Empire', '05-02-2018' );
   $tmpVenue->AddConcert( 'Metallica', '06-02-2018' );
   $tmpVenue->AddConcert( 'Led Zeppelin', '07-02-2018' );
   $tmpVenue->AddConcert( 'Rollin\' Empire', '19-02-2018' );

   //Search For Artist In Venue ( Leave Blank To List All )
   $tmpVenue->ListConcertsInVenue($_GET['bandName']);

?>
```

Would I need to create a new class in app.php to handle the form input and pass it to the other classes?

Comment: what error messages are you getting?

Comment: I was getting a 500

Comment: I rebooted my machine and created new files and it is working!

Comment: ah, the old turn it off and on again

Comment: sometimes you just have to step away haha thanks for the help